# how to hide id number and keep only name in url

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to hide the id number and keep only product name in the url .
My Code so far :

```
<IfModule mode_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^Products/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) product_details.php/(.*)?get_details=$1&&name=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

the output url is : https://mywebadress.com/products/1-product-name

**I want to remove id number "1" from the url and keep only "product-name" .**

Thank you

Comment: Does your products table have an unique index on product-name? If not, how will you query them? If yes, simply modify your back-end code to output URLs without the leading number.

Comment: i don't have unique index sir, is there any alternative way i could use id number to query products but id numbers would not show in the url ?

Comment: Well you do need an unique identifier for each row. Otherwise, how will the system know what's being sought for? products/shoe, products/shoe, or products/shoe? Well they are all they same without the number, aren't they, and that's why you have 1-shoe, 4-shoe, 12-shoe and so on. Basically, *no you can't hide a parameter from an URL and still expect pass it onward to a page*, there are no invisible GET request variables.

Comment: I got it, thanks a lot for your time . Have a great day :)